# Why does this code output the failure message after success?

Tags: python, control-flow

```
  if data.find('!mdcrack') != -1:
     nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')
     m = hashlib.md5()
     hash = ""
     hash_file = str(arg[4])
     wordlist = arg[5]
     try:
         wordlistfile = open(wordlist,"r")
     except IOError:
         sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'invalid file' + '\r\n')
     else:
       pass
     for line in wordlistfile:
                 m = hashlib.md5()  
                 line = line.replace("\n","")
                 m.update(line)
                 word_hash = m.hexdigest()
                 if word_hash==hash_file:
                      sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'Collision!  The word corresponding to the given hash is ' + line + '\r\n')

     sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'The hash given does not correspond to any supplied word in the wordlist' + '\r\n')
```

The code functions by hashing each line from the wordlist, and then comparing it to the hash specified.

I dont get any errors, but when it finds a hash it prints out the `Collision!` message plus the `The hash given does not correspond to any supplied word in the wordlist` message, at first I though it was an ident problem, but now I'm clueless.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it will print 'PRIVSG [..] Collision' and after 'PRIVSG [..] The hash given'.

What you have to do is:

```
collision = False
[..] 
if word_hash==hash_file:
                      sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'Collision!  The word corresponding to the given hash is ' + line + '\r\n')
                      collision = True

if not collision
     sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + " :" 'The hash given does not correspond to any
```

Comment: I'm a getting a `collision = True IndentationError: unexpected indent` error

Comment: Put in the same indent as the line *nick = data.split('!')[ 0 ].replace(':','')*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the "hash does not correspond" message to be sent after a collision is detected, you'll need to return from the function (or otherwise prevent the code from falling through) after the "Collision!" message is sent.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: The "otherwise prevent code from falling through" is what @Pih's answer is suggesting you do.   Do you understand the problem? There's no mechanism in the code right now to stop it from sending the "does not correspond" message after it finds a collision.